# React automatic route issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom v4.3.1. I am facing auto-redirect issue. Below is my code. When I route to `/pli` and `/tli`, I am auto-redirected to `/`. Can anyone help me suggest if there is anything wrong in this route config.

### index

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
   <div>
     <Route path="/" component={Login} />
     <Route path={'/forgotpassword'} component={ForgotPassword} />
     <Route path="/admin" component={App} />
  </div>
 </Router>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

### Login

```
 <Switch>
            <Route exact path={'/'} component={SchoolLogin} />
            <Route exact path={'/tli'} component={TeacherLogin} />
            <Route exact path={'/pli'} component={ParentLogin} />
            <Route path={'/parent/register'} component={RegisterStudent} />
        </Switch>
```